# How HashMap works if an object contains an enum used as Key, as enum hashcode is always random number

Tags: hashmap

I want to understand how hashmap works if an object has enum, because everytime an enum provides a random number. I provide below the code.

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private EmpType eType;
```

//equals() & hashcode() implementation

}

```
public enum EmpType {

PERMANENT,TEMPORARY
```

}

If an object has enum, everytime it provides a different hashcode. If the map is serialized, can we ensure that we can retrieve the same value for a particular object ?

Answer (score 0):

The hash code is varies only from one JVM execution to another. Within one program it remains constant, so hash maps will work fine. Serialization of hash maps doesn't involve storing hash code at all. It just serializes its elements (keys and values) and recalculates hash code when those are deserialized.